# Load modules corresponding to a given commit hash

Tags: python, git, spyder

In some of my Python scripts, I need good traceability of the versions of the modules I use. Until now, I was cloning repos of the modules in directories with a name indicating to which commit they are positioned, like this:

```
mkdir 6107ea5a98392abccf36d37c573aba955b8a7b46
git clone /path/to/some_module 6107ea5a98392abccf36d37c573aba955b8a7b46
cd 6107ea5a98392abccf36d37c573aba955b8a7b46
git checkout 6107ea5a98392abccf36d37c573aba955b8a7b46
```

and in my scripts, I import with these lines:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/.../6107ea5a98392abccf36d37c573aba955b8a7b46/.../')
import some_module
```

This way, I know when looking at my script which version of `some_module` I was using.

But doing so is time-consuming and prone to errors, if for example I checkout by accident one of my folders to the wrong commit.

Are there better ways to keep a hard-coded trace in my python scripts of the module version used? I am thinking of writing a module that uses GitPython and that would automate pretty much what I described above, just when I need it. The module could be loaded like that:

```
my_importer.import('some_module', '6107ea5a98392abccf36d37c573aba955b8a7b46')
```

But maybe such a thing already exists or maybe there are better ways to achieve this...?

Comment: Install the modules, to a virtual environment if necessary; don't import them directly from a Git repository.

Comment: @chepner Not sure I understand. There would be no written trace inside the python scripts files of what virtual environment I used, and hence which versions of the modules were installed. Plus, if I upgrade the modules, this breaks the traceability in the older scripts.

Comment: There are tools (`pip`, etc) for enforcing version dependencies. Inside the script itself is the wrong place to do that.